# useNavigateMock don't receive url

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom, react-testing-library, vitest

I'm trying to test a redirect from my `Login` page using `Vitest + Testing library`. All seems ok until I try to test the `useNavigate` hook. Here is my component:

`Login.tsx`

```js
const userData: User = {
  id: '1',
  name: 'angel',
  permissions: ['management'],
  roles: ['admin'],
}

const fakeAuth = (): Promise<User> =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(userData), 250)
  })

function Login() {
  const { t } = useTranslation()
  const location = useLocation()
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const { login } = useAuth()
  const handleLogin = (e: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    fakeAuth().then((user) => {
      login(user)
      const origin = location.state?.from?.pathname || '/translation'
      navigate(origin)
    })

  }
return (
    <div className="flex min-h-full items-center justify-center px-6 py-8 mx-auto">
      <Card
        title={t('login.title')}
        body={
          <form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
            <button
              data-testid="login-btn"
              type="submit"              
            >
              Login to your account
            </button>
          </form>
        }
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

And the test file, I use a mock to do it:

`Login.test.tsx`

```js
import { describe, it, vi } from 'vitest'
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import * as router from 'react-router-dom'
import Login from './Login'

const mockedUsedNavigate = vi.fn()

vi.mock('react-router-dom', async () => {
  return {
    ...((await vi.importActual('react-router-dom')) as any),
    useNavigate: () => mockedUsedNavigate,
  }
})

describe('Login Page', () => {
  const user = userEvent.setup()

  it('Call the useNavigate when user click', async () => {
    const navigate = vi.spyOn(router, 'useNavigate')

    render(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/login']}>
        <Login />
      </MemoryRouter>
    )

    const loginBtn = screen.getByTestId('login-btn')

    user.click(loginBtn)

    expect(navigate).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(navigate).toBeCalledWith('/translation')
  })
})
```

The first expect work fine. But the second one throws this error:

`AssertionError: expected "useNavigate" to be called with arguments: [ '/translation' ]expected "useNavigate" to be called with arguments: [ '/translation' ]`

My dependencies and vite config

```json
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",,
    "react-router-dom": "^6.6.2",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^8.19.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "jsdom": "^21.0.0",
    "vite": "^4.0.4",
    "vitest": "^0.27.0"
```

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
    setupFiles: ['./src/setupTest.ts'],
    coverage: {
      reporter: ['text', 'json', 'html'],
    },
  },
})
```

Honestly I don't know what more to do. All the examples i saw works perfectly doing this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance